# Combine graphs from two different datasets

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr

I am trying to see how word frequency correlates with phonotactic probability using R, but there are a few issues. First, and most generally, I don't know merge these two graphs together (i want them to appear on the same axis).
[image]
[image: ![enter image description here]

This leads to a second problem because the first graph's y values are in probabilities, and the second is a count, so the scales are not the same. Should I combine data frames first, or is there a simpler way to merge two graphs?

Here is the reproducible sample, and the code for my graphs:

```
Phonotactic_Probability <-structure(list(Word = c("Baby", "Bagel", "Bandage", "Banjo", 
 "Carriage", "Carrot", "Chicken", "Chipmunk", "City", "Cobra", 
 "Cocoa", "Fairy", "Ferret", "Garbage", "Garlic", "Letter", "Lettuce", 
 "Lobster", "Locker", "Marble", "Marker", "Muffin", "Mushroom", 
 "Pasta", "Peacock", "Peanut", "Possum", "Puppet", "Puppy", "Raccoon", 
 "Racket", "Rooster", "Ruler", "Sandal", "Sandwich", "Scissors", 
 "Turkey", "Turtle", "Whistle", "Wizard"), `Biphone Probability...5` = c(0.0029, 
 0.0023, 0.0274, 0.012, 0.025, 0.02, 0.0048, 0.0019, 0.0029, 0.0057, 
 4e-04, 2e-04, 0.0085, 0.0209, 0.0199, 0.0061, 0.0044, 0.0168, 
 0.0014, 0.0222, 0.0202, 0.0033, 0.004, 0.0265, 4e-04, 0.0044, 
 0.0045, 0.009, 0.0025, 0.0023, 0.0079, 0.0153, 0.0031, 0.0278, 
 0.0265, 0.008, 0.0042, 0.0107, 0.0163, 0.0064), `Biphone Probability` = c(0.0029, 
 0.0023, 0.0274, 0.012, 0.025, 0.02, 0.0048, 0.0019, 0.0029, 0.0057, 
 4e-04, 2e-04, 0.0085, 0.0209, 0.0199, 0.0061, 0.0044, 0.0168, 
 0.0014, 0.0222, 0.0202, 0.0033, 0.004, 0.0265, 4e-04, 0.0044, 
 0.0045, 0.009, 0.0025, 0.0023, 0.0079, 0.0153, 0.0031, 0.0278, 
 0.0265, 0.008, 0.0042, 0.0107, 0.0163, 0.0064)), class = c("grouped_df", 
 "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -40L), groups = structure(list(
 Word = c("Baby", "Bagel", "Bandage", "Banjo", "Carriage", 
 "Carrot", "Chicken", "Chipmunk", "City", "Cobra", "Cocoa", 
 "Fairy", "Ferret", "Garbage", "Garlic", "Letter", "Lettuce", 
 "Lobster", "Locker", "Marble", "Marker", "Muffin", "Mushroom", 
 "Pasta", "Peacock", "Peanut", "Possum", "Puppet", "Puppy", 
 "Raccoon", "Racket", "Rooster", "Ruler", "Sandal", "Sandwich", 
 "Scissors", "Turkey", "Turtle", "Whistle", "Wizard"), .rows = structure(list(
 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
 "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
 ), row.names = c(NA, -40L), .drop = TRUE))
```

```
###Phonotactic Plot
Phonotactic_Probability %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = `Biphone Probability`, x = reorder(Word,`Biphone Probability`), col = "red")) + 
  labs(y= "Biphone Probability", x = "Target word")+
  geom_point(size = 2)+ 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45))+
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

```
###Word Frequency df
 Word_Frequency <- structure(list(Word = c("Baby", "Bagel", "Bandage", "Banjo", 
 "Carriage", "Carrot", "Chicken", "Chipmunk", "City", "Cobra", 
 "Cocoa", "Fairy", "Ferret", "Garbage", "Garlic", "Letter", "Lettuce", 
 "Lobster", "Locker", "Marble", "Marker", "Muffin", "Mushroom", 
 "Pasta", "Peacock", "Peanut", "Possum", "Puppet", "Puppy", "Raccoon", 
 "Racket", "Rooster", "Ruler", "Sandal", "Sandwich", "Scissors", 
 "Turkey", "Turtle", "Whistle", "Wizard"), `Frequency (Google Books)` = c(6127799, 
 29335, 428865, 125242, 2505730, 215525, 1724136, 30591, 30586130, 
 69450, 382604, 1082454, 115446, 674079, 651590, 20168453, 353798, 
 256454, 271988, 1996235, 769873, 81982, 270867, 238173, 149644, 
 277100, 76104, 384574, 316058, 73050, 268584, 136815, 1659585, 
 81154, 430627, 511265, 1763068, 396105, 778168, 309233), Freq10k = c(612.7799, 
 2.9335, 42.8865, 12.5242, 250.573, 21.5525, 172.4136, 3.0591, 
 3058.613, 6.945, 38.2604, 108.2454, 11.5446, 67.4079, 65.159, 
 2016.8453, 35.3798, 25.6454, 27.1988, 199.6235, 76.9873, 8.1982, 
 27.0867, 23.8173, 14.9644, 27.71, 7.6104, 38.4574, 31.6058, 7.305, 
 26.8584, 13.6815, 165.9585, 8.1154, 43.0627, 51.1265, 176.3068, 
 39.6105, 77.8168, 30.9233)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", 
 "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -40L), groups = structure(list(
 Word = c("Baby", "Bagel", "Bandage", "Banjo", "Carriage", 
 "Carrot", "Chicken", "Chipmunk", "City", "Cobra", "Cocoa", 
 "Fairy", "Ferret", "Garbage", "Garlic", "Letter", "Lettuce", 
 "Lobster", "Locker", "Marble", "Marker", "Muffin", "Mushroom", 
 "Pasta", "Peacock", "Peanut", "Possum", "Puppet", "Puppy", 
 "Raccoon", "Racket", "Rooster", "Ruler", "Sandal", "Sandwich", 
 "Scissors", "Turkey", "Turtle", "Whistle", "Wizard"), .rows = structure(list(
 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 11L, 12L, 13L, 
 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 18L, 19L, 20L, 21L, 22L, 23L, 24L, 
 25L, 26L, 27L, 28L, 29L, 30L, 31L, 32L, 33L, 34L, 35L, 
 36L, 37L, 38L, 39L, 40L), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
 "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
 ), row.names = c(NA, -40L), .drop = TRUE))
```

```
### Word Frequency Plot
Word_Frequency %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = Freq10k, x = reorder(Word,Freq10k))) + 
  labs(y= "Word frequency per 10k", x = "Target word")+
  geom_point(size = 2)+ 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45))+
  scale_color_brewer(palette = "Set1")
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you have your issues backwards: first issue is what scale do you want the final plot to be, frequency or probability? This is a question we can't answer for you. Second issue is transforming the data frame in the wrong format to match. Do you need help with that?  Then putting them on the same plot is easy, you use `geom_point(data = data1, ...) + geom_point(data = data2, ...)`.

Comment: Thank you, and okay. I guess I could divide each value by the largest frequency value to get percentages. What comes after I reference the data frame in geom_point(data = data1, ...)? In other words, what replaces the "..."?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way could be to use a second y axis. Although this method is to be used critically, in this situation I think it is appropriate:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- left_join(Phonotactic_Probability, Word_Frequency, by="Word")

coeff <- 100000

ggplot(df, aes(x = reorder(Word,`Biphone Probability`))) +
  geom_point(aes(y = `Biphone Probability`), size = 4, color = "red")+
  geom_point(aes(y = Freq10k / coeff), shape=23, fill="blue", size=4) +
  scale_y_continuous(
    name = "Biphone Probability",
    sec.axis = sec_axis(~.*coeff, name = "Word frequency per 10k")
  ) +
  xlab("\nTarget word")+
  theme_bw(14)+
  theme(
    axis.title.y = element_text(color = "red", size=13, face="bold"),
    axis.title.y.right = element_text(color = "blue", size=13, face="bold"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, vjust = 0.5, hjust=1)
  ) +
  ggtitle("Biphone Probability and Word frequency per 10k")
```

[image]

Comment: this is perfect. Thank you. is there i way i can do this with multiple graphs? I am actually tracking more than these 2 metrics. Thanks again!

Comment: Depends on the data. I am sure it is possible. Best is to open a new question with a minimal reproducible example!